# Cache/Remember a not fixed cell value and insert it in another cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script, where I go to the last cell (which is always a different row), and want to transfer the cell value from the next right cell.
Then go six cells to the right, and insert the copied value.

The // COPY VALUE and // PASTE THE COPIED VALUE are my problem because I don't have a fixed cell.

Image: orange value to the orange cell

[image]

```
// Jump to the End
spreadsheet.getRange('G10').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();

// go one step to the right
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();

// COPY VALUE
???

// go six steps to the right and PASTE THE COPIED VALUE
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 6).activate();
spreadsheet.getRange('???').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you the detail of your question? Where do you want to copy the value from? By the way, I cannot see the cell coordinate from your sample image. For example, do you want to copy all values of column "G" to column "M"?

Comment: The value comes from the last Cell in column G +1 to the right from column H. That's why I use `SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN`.
I want to copy the value from the single Cell in column H to the column N, but in the same row. The columns are always the same, but the rows change with every Entry.
I add another Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `The value comes from the last Cell in column G +1 to the right from column H. That's why I use SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN. I want to copy the value from the single Cell in column H to column N, but in the same row. The columns are always the same, but the rows change with every Entry.`, I understood your expected result as follows.

- You want to copy the value from column "H" of the last row to column "N".

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Sample script:

The last row can be retrieved with `getLastRow()` of Class Sheet. And, in order to copy the value, `copyTo` of Class Rabge can be used.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // or  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var srcRange = sheet.getRange("H" + sheet.getLastRow());
  srcRange.copyTo(srcRange.offset(0, 6), { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

- In this case, the value from column "H" of the last row is copied to column "N".
- As another approach, when you want to use `getValue` and `setValue`, you can also use the following sample script.

  ```js
  function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // or  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    var srcRange = sheet.getRange("H" + sheet.getLastRow());
    srcRange.offset(0, 6).setValue(srcRange.getValue());
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var getval = sheet.getRange(lastrow,2).getValue();
  sheet.getRange(lastrow, 2).offset(0,6).setValue(getval);

}
```

What this does is that it goes to the last row of the sheet, and gets the value of the lat row Col2, and offsets 6 cells to the right, and copies the value to the given offset.